# How to give the first element inside a class font-size of 150% and the first line of that element red?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code snippet in HTML below:

```css
.container:first-child::first-line{
font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Veggies es <a href="http://example.com">bonus vobis</a>, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic.</p>
  <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Vegetables</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Potato</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Carrot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tomato</td>
      <td>Parsnip</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwi</td>
      <td>Onion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Beet</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, I want the first paragraph and the first line to be exactly like the image below:
[The final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekGmv.jpg)

Comment: Please show your effort

Comment: What do you mean by "*first line*"?  As rendered?

Comment: The first element which is '<p>' should have the font size of 150%, and for the first line of it should have the red color.

Comment: Which first line? Which sentence? From "Veggies" to "gralic"?

Answer (score 0):

To make the first child of font size 150%:

```
.container p:first-child {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

To make the first line red:

```
.container p:first-child:first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there a general rule that only selects the first child regardless of the element type for this code above?

Comment: Yes, just replace the tag name with `>`. In the above case replace `p` element with `>` in both styles (`.container>:first-child` & `.container>:first-child:first-line`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use p::first-line, not :first-child.
::first-line selects only the first line of a paragraph, while first-child selects the first paragraph, which could be shown on multiple lines.

Moreover, you have to set the color property, not background.

```
.container p::first-line{
    color: red;
}
```

In this case all the paragraphs will have the first line red. If you want only a specific paragraph, you can assign it an ID and then use first:line.

EDIT:
To have also the first paragraph with font-size 150%, you can use :first-child:

```
.container p:first-child{
    font-size:150%;
}
.container  p:first-child::first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I also want the font size of this paragraph as I earlier mentioned to to be 150% (the whole paragraph not just the first line).

Comment: you can use the p:first-child to select only the first paragraph. I've edited my answer. Check!